# Java object and random numbers

Tags: java, class, object, random, methods

If I call this :

```
math a = new math ();
for (x=0; ×<5;x++){
    a.addition ();
}
```

In main class^

```
import java.util.*;
public class math
{   
    Scanner scan = new     Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        private int num1 = rand.nextInt(100);
        private int num2 = rand.nextInt(100);
      private int correctanswers = 0;

public void addition(){
    System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = ");
    int answer = scan.nextInt();
    if (answer == (num1 + num2)){
           correctanswers++;
    }
}

    public int getcorrectanswers(){
    return correctanswers;
    }
}
```

What I get is the same numbers each time it goes around the 'for' loop (5 times) what I want to know is how do I get those numbers to be different each time it goes over the 'for' loop when a.addition() gets called
So for example:
it will print 5+7 each time rather than doing 2 different numbers each time obviously what I want is 5+2 then 4+50 etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because

```
private int num1 = rand.nextInt(100);
private int num2 = rand.nextInt(100);
```

are fields of the math object. Both are initialize *once* upon `new math()`.

Put them as local variables inside the `addition` method instead:

```
public void addition(){
    int num1 = rand.nextInt(100);
    int num2 = rand.nextInt(100);
    System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = ");
    int answer = scan.nextInt();
    if (answer == (num1 + num2)){
           correctanswers++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So by this answer there is no need for me to be doing this as an object I might as well just have methods in my main?

Comment: You could do it in your main method, but splitting up the program into several classes as you've started doing with the `math` class is good practice. To encapsulate `rand` and `correctAnswers` variables in a class is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know I'm going the right way! I've got it finished now math class doing add,multiply,divide,subtract.. its a little game/project that gives the user 5 sums based on what they input (-,×,+,÷) was a fun Lil project and all works thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome. Nice to hear that you got it working :-)

Answer (score 0):

The random int at your math class is the same everytime you call addition() .
Add to 'addition' -> num1 =r.nextInt() 
To get a new random number for 'num1'

Comment: Do u mean rand.nextInt or is r.nextInt A different thing altogether

Comment: Im sorry Yeah i meant 'rand' ... Sorry I wrote this with my phone and it's a little bit complicated to switch between answer and code

Comment: I know I put this question up on my phone and it is awkward